# Tell if a variable is defined in boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: variables, debugging, bjam, boost-build, b2

For debug purposes, how can I see if a variable is set in b2 ?

aka. test if a variable is defined in b2

Comment: There might be a solution using `sequence.module`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply test the value of `$(variable_name)-is-not-empty`:

```
if $(variable_name)-not-empty
{
    echo "not empty" ;
}
else
{
    echo "empty" ;
}
```

this is how `assert.variable-not-empty` is implemented. It works because an undefined variable is the [same](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables) as an empty list and because concatenating the string "-not-empty" to an empty list with [variable expansion](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables.expansion) gives an empty list, which is equivalent to *false*.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect, but it is possible to tell if a variable is defined using an echo and [Variable expansion](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables.expansion):

```
:E=value
    Assign value to the variable if it is unset.
```

Example:

```
echo "Variable FOO has value $(FOO:E=was_not_previously_set)" ;
```

Will display:
`Variable FOO has value was_not_previously_set` if `FOO` was unset before the call to echo.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to assert that the variable is defined, you can do:

```
import assert ;
assert.variable-not-empty variable_name ;
```

note: I did not write `$(variable_name)` (it is evaluated).

If the assert fails it displays:

```
jamfile:line: in modules.load from module Jamfile<C:\path\to\jamfile\dir>
error: assertion failure: Expected variable "variable_name" not to be an empty list
```

This works because in b2, as the doc [says](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables), "An undefined variable is indistinguishable from a variable with an empty list".

This kind of assert is useful for example if you want to produce a target name by concatenating: `$(ModuleName_TOP)/project//target` because this would become the empty list if `ModuleName_TOP` was not defined, causing build errors instead of b2 errors.